# MS Visual Studio Express Edition

Tags: visual-studio

i have heard that MS VS express editions are free and light weight and are more suitable for students and beginners etc.i have install VS 2012 express edition but it is still saying that this product will expire in 30 days.i want to know that whether express editions of visual studios are really free or not?i have download it from Microsoft official site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign into Visual Studio in order to continue to use the product after the 30 days are up.

To unlock Express Editions:

On the Help menu, click Register Product.

Click the Register now link to get your free key to unlock your
   Express Edition.

Sign in to Passport and then fill out the online registration form.

On the Thank you for registering page, copy the key.

In your Express Edition, paste the key in the Registration Key text
   box and then click Complete Registration.

You need a Microsoft Account to do that.